# Sencha Touch - menu and edge swipes errors

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I'm wondering if anyone has found a fix for the issue, when the menu is initialized but has not been shown yet and the user makes edge swipes what leads to ST throwing errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined.

Please see here what I mean (open console and make edge swipes):
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3vq

More about that:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?281225

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hot fix for Sencha Touch 2.4.1 side menu slide issue [TOUCH-5328](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?281225):

replace in `touch\src\viewport\Default.js` line `1043`

```
if (checkMenu.isHidden() !== false) {
```

with

```
if (checkMenu.isHidden() == false) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Converted the equality operator to the identity operator:

```
if (checkMenu.isHidden() === false) {
```